# Getting the BeanCreationException after adding Swagger Implementation in Springboot RestApi

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jax-rs, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Below i have added the code in which after adding Swagger2feature i'm getting

`BeanCreationException , BeanInstantiationException and NoSuchMethodError(io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.setUsePathBasedConfig(Z)V)`

### Main Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TechpubsServicesSBApp.class, args);
} 

@Bean
public Server rsServer() {
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    endpoint.setBus(bus);
    endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.<Object>asList(testImpl));
    endpoint.setAddress("/");
    endpoint.setProviders(Arrays.<Object>asList(testExceptionMapper));
    endpoint.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
    Swagger2Feature swagger2Feature = new Swagger2Feature();
    swagger2Feature.setTitle("Test API");
    swagger2Feature.setVersion(deployedVersion.concat("(").concat(deployedInstance.toUpperCase()).concat(")"));
    swagger2Feature.setPrettyPrint(true);
    swagger2Feature.setSupportSwaggerUi(true);       
    endpoint.setFeatures(Collections.singletonList(swagger2Feature));
    return endpoint.create();
    }</i>
```

### Error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rsServer' defined in com.geaviation.techpubs.ws.TechpubsServicesSBApp: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server]: Factory method 'rsServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.setUsePathBasedConfig(Z)V
```

Have anyone faced similar kind of error ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar kind of error. My problem was that I had multiple swagger dependencies in my build.gradle. Before I got rid of the error my build.gradle looked similar to this:

```
    compile "org.webjars:swagger-ui:3.9.2"
    compile "io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.10"
    compile "io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:1.5.0"
```

What solved the problem was a build.gradle looking like this:

```
compile "org.webjars:swagger-ui:3.9.2"
```

I removed the io.swagger dependencies and it worked for me. A final rsServer setup could look something like this later and hopefully work with the swagger2feature enabled ;).

```
 @Bean
  public Server rsServer() {
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    endpoint.setBus(bus);

    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
    endpoint.setProviders(providers);

    endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.<Object>asList(myService()));

    endpoint.setAddress("/");
    endpoint.getFeatures().add(serviceConfiguration.swagger2Feature());
    return endpoint.create();
  }
```